# How to create documentation for a package with roxygen2 in a language different from English?

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I am trying to create documentation in Russian but get "Warning: unable to re-encode" and a kind of mess instead of documentation like "<8e>..."

Is it possible to generate documentation with roxygen2 in a language different from English?

Comment: I don't think you can. I would suggest that you only write the vignette in both langages.